# Construct an array where each element is also an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, element

I'm a bit new to matlab, so please bear with me, I'm not 100% sure if what I want to do can actually be done.

So, I have an array

```
coords = zeros(2000, 2);
```

and another array representing the actual coordinates

```
pixCoords = [35 200] %dummy values
```

How can I/ what is the syntax to assign `pixCoords` to the (1,1) position of `coords`, such that when I type in `coords(1,1)` the console will return `35 200`?

Eventually, each column of `coords` will have two different sets of coordinates in them.

Thanks!

Comment: If every element of your desired array will have a 2 element vector, you probably just want to use a 3D matrix here rather than cell arrays. They're much easier to work with in MATLAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe **cell arrays** are your friends here.

```
coords = {};
coords{1, 1} = [35 200];

% now you want to retrieve the array
coords{1, 1}
% ans = 
%    35   200
```

And you can of course add new arrays to other positions in your cell array using the same notation.